# pChart - running scripts as www-data doesn't work

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, pchart

So I'm having trouble running PHP scripts for pChart. Running them as the user who created them works fine, but if I sudo to www-data, I get these errors:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  include(/usr/lib/pchart/class/pDraw.class.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/usr/lib/pchart/class/pDraw.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  include(/usr/lib/pchart/class/pImage.class.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/usr/lib/pchart/class/pImage.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  include(/usr/lib/pchart/class/pData.class.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/usr/lib/pchart/class/pData.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'pData' not found in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/test.php on line 10
```

Does anyone have any idea what permissions or groups I'd need to change to get this working?  I've tried changing everything mentioned in the output above to 777 but it's still happening.

Comment: try with change file ownership like: chown www-data finename

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  Seeing as I've tried changing all the files mentioned, I'm probably targeting the wrong file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was permissions, though it's not clear which ones yet.  It started working when I changed the pChart2.1.3 folder permissions to 777.  Now I can tidy up.